# link from image index to slideshow

Tags: javascript

Two puzzles.

I have an image index of thumbnails, and I would like to link from each particular thumbnail to the slideshow of larger images, at the slide number associated with the image the thumbnail represents.

The slide show works great, and displays captions for each slide, but I do not know how to link from outside the slideshow to a particular slide in the sequence.

And the second puzzle: as it is written now, the slideshow can only run linearly from 1 through whatever and associates the captions as though no matter what image is displayed, the slideshow is starting with caption one. So I am also unable to make however many different html documents, to each start the slide show at the image I want, so that although tedious, I could link from any thumbnail to the slideshow, starting the slideshow at that image. But the captions and slides are matched, so that doesn't work either-- if I put any other image besides slide0, the caption displayed is still and always the caption associated with slide0. And if I start the id=slideshow with any image other than the first in the sequence, and navigate forward, I get image 2, no matter what number image I started with, and going to the previous image will always get me the last image in the slide show, no matter which slide number was displayed via html.

Here is the slideshow script:

```
window.onload = initAll;

var currImg = 0;
var captionText = new Array(
"Wrangler, Darhat Valley, Mongolia",
"Graveyard, Camden, Maine",
"Pants, Inis M&oacute;r",
"Campfire Lake, Crazy Mountains, Montana",
"Campsite, Darhat Valley",
"Crazy Mountains, Montana",
"Cuddy, Bedlam",
"The River Styx",
"Fountain, Cambridge",
"Freezeout Lake, Spring Equinox 1",
"Freezeout Lake, Spring Equinox 2",
"Freezeout Lake, Spring Equinox 3",
"G. I. Joe, Darhat Valley",
"Girls in Red, Renchilumbe, Mongolia",
"After spring rains, Montana",
"Lake Helena, Montana",
"Kapiti Coast, New Zealand",
"Lucky Star Bar, Inis M&oacute;r",
"On Ponsonby, Auckland",
"Holding Reservoir, Montana",
"Ferry, Darhat Valley",
"Baja",
"Saridag Inn, Renchilumbe",
"Skyscapes",
"Stanley Lane, Vermont",
"Bear Gulch, Montana",
"On the train between Brussels and Paris",
"Great blue heron",
"Tree, Tulla",
"Waves, Dun Aengus",
"Two ladies",
"Walls, Inis M&oacute;r",
"Wave, Dun Aengus",
"Storm light, Northampton"
)

function initAll() {
document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[0];
document.getElementById("prevLink").onclick = processPrevious;
document.getElementById("nextLink").onclick = processNext;
}

function processPrevious() {
newSlide(-1);
}

function processNext() {
newSlide(1);
}

function newSlide(direction) {
var imgCt = captionText.length;

currImg = currImg + direction;
if (currImg < 0) {
    currImg = imgCt-1;
}
if (currImg == imgCt) {
    currImg = 0;
}
document.getElementById("slideshow").src = "slides/slides" + currImg + ".png";
document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[currImg];
}
```

I am not a programmer, that's probably obvious. I adapt scripts that are offered.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Hi @User, welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to your problem lies in the `newSlide(direction)` line.  If you modified this function to accept an image number rather than a direction, you could call it whenever you need to:

```
// Since this function handles backwards movement, keep all backwards-moving
// logic contained inside of it. Same for forward movement.
function prev() {
    currImg = currImg - 1;

    // This should be called from the wherever prev() is called from,
    // but for the sake of the example I'll include it here.
    show();
}

function next() {
    currImg = currImg + 1;

    // ...see above...
    show();
}

// Make sure the currImg is valid here, whenever you need to.
function check() {
    if (currImg >= captionText.length) {
        currImg = 0;
    }

    if (currImg < 0) {
        currImg = captionText.length - 1;
    }
}

// Now, this function shows whatever slide, whatever caption.
function show() {
    check();
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src = "slides/slides" + currImg + ".png";
    document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[currImg];
}


function initAll() {
    document.getElementById("imgText").innerHTML = captionText[0];
    document.getElementById("prevLink").onclick = processPrevious;
    document.getElementById("nextLink").onclick = processNext;

    // You can set the image you want during init, or update it in 
    // a different function and show() again.
    currImg = 0;
    show();
};
```

To set the image to whatever you want, you can just modify `currImg` as required, using GET or a form input or something.